# Value from Promise.all not always interpreted by Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a controller like so:

```
controller.things = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
controller.loading = true;
controller.responses = [];

controller.handlePromises = function(){
   var promises = [];

   for(promiseIndex = 0; promiseIndex < controller.things.length; promiseIndex++) {
        promises.push(controller.promise(things[promiseIndex]);
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function success(response){
        for(responseIndex = 0; responseIndex < response.length; responseIndex++){
           responses.push(response[responseIndex].data);
        }
        controller.loading = false;
    }
}

controller.promise = function(value){
   //Some $http request to Database;
}

controller.handlePromises();
```

The amount of stuff in `controller.things` depends on the user. Attached to this is a simple html page that does the following:

```
<div ng-if="!controller.loading">
    <div ng-repeat="response in controller.responses">
       {{response}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that there's a 50/50 chance for the content to become visible, the other times I can see in the debugger that the promises have been resolved and loading is set to false, but the ng-if keeps hiding the content. Even if the content is shown, there's a good chance that the ng-repeat says `controller.responses` is still empty.

**How can I guarantee that the ng-if accepts `controller.loading` as false when the promises have been resolved, no matter how long it takes? Also, same question for the ng-repeat not seeing the values in `controller.responses` sometimes.** I've considered a timeout, but that isn't the ideal solution as it can take anywhere between half a second to ten seconds.

Comment: Does all the promises succeed? You only have a success callback in your Promise.all(...). I would guess that you don't end up in the success callback if one or more of the promises will fail?

Comment: The example assumes that all promises are resolved succesfully, the actual full implementation has a fail fallback.

Comment: Did you try $digest.apply() or $scope.apply(). Chances are UI don't get update about scope has been changed.

Comment: Use `$q` instead of `Promise`, it'll trigger the digest cycle for you

Comment: @Dieterg, this solved it, altough I understand you shouldn't write answers in comments. Could you maybe add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using `Promise.all` instead of `$q`. `$q` is a Promise library built by the Angular team that'll do the `$digest` cycle for you.

```
$q.all(promises).then(function success(response) {
  for (responseIndex = 0; responseIndex < response.length; responseIndex++) {
    responses.push(response[responseIndex].data);
  }
  controller.loading = false;
});
```

[Read more about $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)